# how to get the php-cli version 7 in cmd prompt

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I installed one Xampp with Php5 version and other xmapp with php7 version in different folders, but db is same for both xmapps. When I run the

**php -v**

in command prompt in both folders, it only show as php version as 5. How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the environment value in system for php.exe (set the php7 path to env).
eg:

Old path: D:xmapp/php/php.exe

new path: D:xmapp7/php/php.exe